# BBCODE to HTML in Android Java

Tags: java, android

I currently have 1 piece HTML string
and which contains 2 type is BBCode

```
[AUDIO description] mylink [AUDIO]

[AUDIO] mylink [AUDIO]
```

How to replace it

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="mylink" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="mylink" type="audio/mpeg">
description 
</audio>
```

To run in html
I have tried using **regex** and **replace** unsuccessfully.

Thank you very much

Example :

```
<p>[AUDIO id=1441618092334 alt=hola halo ola ]http://try.yourname.com/thesound.mp3[/AUDIO]</p>
```

Replace it to :

```
    <audio controls>
      <source src="http://try.yourname.com/thesound.mp3" 
type="audio/mpeg">

   hola halo ola 
    </audio>
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've tried or this will be closed.

Comment: Please make an [edit] to your question.

Comment: sr, i fixed it , tks

Answer (score 1):

Try KefirBB. It works on Android and allows to convert BBcodes to HTML.
https://github.com/kefirfromperm/kefirbb